# How to fix module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_session'

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Help solve that problem please 
I use ImageAI to detect cars , but it didn't works , i'm newbee in this , sorry

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os


execution_path = os.getcwd()

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
detector.loadModel()

detections, objects_path = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path , "image3.jpg"), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , "image3new.jpg"), minimum_percentage_probability=30,  extract_detected_objects=True)


for eachObject, eachObjectPath in zip(detections, objects_path):
    print(eachObject["name"] , " : " , eachObject["percentage_probability"], " : ", eachObject["box_points"] )
    print("Object's image saved in " + eachObjectPath)
    print("--------------------------------")
```

Using TensorFlow backend.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/maxim/PycharmProjects/ImageAI/venv/image.py", line 7, in <module>
    detector = ObjectDetection()
File "/home/maxim/.virtualenvs/ImageAI/lib/python3.5/site-packages/imageai/Detection/__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.sess = K.get_session()
  File "/home/maxim/.virtualenvs/ImageAI/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 174, in get_session
    default_session = tf.get_default_session()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_session'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please organize your question better.its not clear at all the structure of your code and the error

Comment: Organized . sorry i'm first day on that platform. :c

Comment: Are you using tensorflow 2.0?

Comment: Yeah , i'm install 2.0 because on 1.14 was a lot of errors , and i find recommendation to install 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/issues/563

You're right it (ImageAI) works with Collecting keras==2.1.6, checked on colob, Thanks

Comment: You can test it: (keras==2.1.6, tensorflow==1.15.3)

https://github.com/maxkleiner/maXbox4/blob/master/objectdetector3.ipynb