# How to fix 'RuntimeError: `get_session` is not available when using TensorFlow 2.0.'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to python and I have be trying to run this code. But I keep getting this error.

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os

execution_path = os.getcwd()

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
detector.loadModel()
self.sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()
detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path , "image.jpg"), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , "imagenew.jpg"))

for eachObject in detections:
    print(eachObject["name"] , " : " , eachObject["percentage_probability"] )
```

I am supposed to get the percentage for the objects in the image but instead I am getting this:

> Using TensorFlow backend. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "detector.py", line 6, in 
>       detector = ObjectDetection()   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection__init__.py", line
>   88, in **init**
>       self.sess = K.get_session()   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 379, in get_session
>       '`get_session` is not available ' RuntimeError: `get_session` is not available when using TensorFlow 2.0.

Comment: Tensorflow 2.0 defaults to eager execution and i don't think get_session() is supported with eager.

Comment: I am new to this. Could you suggest a solution?

Comment: you may have to consider using tensorflow 1.15 or any version lower than 2.0

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Earlier I had tried it with version 1.12 and didn't work but worked with 1.15.

Answer (score 10):

**Answer:**
In **TF 2.0** you should use `tf.compat.v1.Session()` instead of `tf.Session()`
Use the following code to get rid of the error in `Tensorflow2.0`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.Session()
```

i.e. in your code above, replace this line `self.sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()`of code with

```
self.sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
```

Reference:

1. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26844#issuecomment-474038678

Answer (score 1):

'get_session' is not available when using tensorflow 2.0. It is available in tensorflow 1.14.0

Just write in the command line

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone else had the same issue. they didn't mark an answer though.

[How to fix module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_session'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961839/how-to-fix-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-get-default-session)

The code there worked for me after downloading the model and a test image.

you might need the cudnn library https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html

The result should look like this

[image: running resnet50 cocos model]

Comment: now I am getting this:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no attribute 'get_graph'

Comment: reinstall keras with pip
or it could be your tensorflow install maybe.

Comment: Check Tensor flow version
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'  # for Python 3
Check Keras version
python3 -c 'import keras ; print(keras.__version__)'  # for Python 3

Answer (score 0):

As Tensorflow website (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) suggest about migrate, you could import tensorflow as following to keep compatibility when you have tensorflow 2.0 installed:
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

Answer (score 0):

Any one with this get_session. This worked for me and I would like to share. Replace the line self.sess = K.get_session() with self.sess = tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession()