# After downgrading Tensorflow 2.0 to 1.5 results changed and results reproduction is not available

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, shap

Would you help me to achieve reproducible results with Tensorflow 1.15 without restarting Python kernel. And why the output results in TF 2.0 and TF 1.5 are different with absolutely identical parameters and dataset? Is it possible to achieve identical output?

More details:
I tried to interpret model results in TF 2.0 by:

```
import shap
background = df3.iloc[np.random.choice(df3.shape[0], 100, replace=False)]
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model,  background)
```

I recieved an error:

```
`get_session` is not available when using TensorFlow 2.0.`get_session` is not available when using TensorFlow 2.0.
```

According to the [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58556906/how-to-fix-runtimeerror-get-session-is-not-available-when-using-tensorflow-2), I tried to setup TF 2.0 compatibility with TF 1 by using in the front of my code:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

But the error appeared again.
Following advice by many users, I downgraded TF2 to TF 1.15 it solved the problem, and shap module interprets the results but:
1) to make results reproducible now I have to change tf.random.set_seed(7) on tf.random.set_random_seed(7) and restart the Python kernel every time! In TF2 I didn't have to restart the kernel.
2) prediction results has been changed, especially, Economical efficiency (that is, TF1.5.  wrongly classifies more important samples than TF2.0).

TF 2:
Accuracy: 94.95%, Economical efficiency = 64%

TF 1:
Accuracy: 94.85%, Economical efficiency = 56%

The code of the model is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078946/how-to-get-reproducible-results-keras-tensorflow/61113427#61113427)

Answer (score 2):

First, results differ from each other not only in TF1 and TF2 versions, but also in TF2.0 and TF2.2 versions. Probably, it depends on diffenent internal parameters in the packages.

Second, TensorFlow2 works with DeepExplainer in the following versions:

```
import tensorflow
import pandas as pd
import keras
import xgboost
import numpy
import shap
print(tensorflow.__version__)
print(pd.__version__)
print(keras.__version__)
print(xgboost.__version__)
print(numpy.__version__)
print(shap.__version__)
```

output:

```
2.2.0
0.24.2
2.3.1
0.90
1.17.5
0.35.0
```

But you will face some difficulties in updating the libraries.

In Python 3.5, running TF2.2, you will face the error 'DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found'.
It 100% can be solved by installing newer C++ package. See this:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794#issuecomment-573297027
Link to download the package:https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

In Python 3.7 you will not find the shap 0.35.0 version with whl extention. Only tar.gz extension which gives the error: "Install visual c++ package". But installation doesn't help.
Then download shap 0.35.0 for Python 3.7 here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/shap/files. Run Anaconda shell. Type: conda install -c conda-forge C:\shap-0.35.0-py37h3bbf574_0.tar.bz2.